# What are some overlay/expose jquery plugins?

Tags: jquery

I've used Jquery Tools and Fancybox. But these plugins dont work properly in my school's template when using older browser versions like firefox 3.0.1.6

I need to try different plugins with the hopes of them working.

Comment: Can you add details of what you're trying to accomplish? There are so many different jQuery plugins, it would be tedious to list all that do overlays.

Comment: i want to add a swf. Right now Shadowbox works best for me but it scales with the browser and i dont know how to modify it.

Answer (score 0):

You could just make your own, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785762/how-to-add-a-full-sized-image-to-the-center-of-a-webpage-using-jquery/1787976#1787976).