# How would i implement swfobject in this jquery overlay?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[How to add a full-sized image to the center of a webpage using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785762/how-to-add-a-full-sized-image-to-the-center-of-a-webpage-using-jquery/1787976#1787976)

The code the guy posted...

Answer (score 1):

SWFobject simply targets a tag by it's ID and writes the appropriate code.  First step would be to use Javascript to call SWFobject using the ID of the appropriate div from your example.  Say your ID is overlayFLASH...

swfobject.embedSWF("myContent.swf", "overlayFLASH", "300", "120", "9.0.0",'', '', '', '');

See the documentation for the other parameters and features (I've pared some stuff out for simplicity)... http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation