# how to add background image using jquery script on html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add few images for my game scoreboard as background using jquery.

eg. header.jpg for header, footer.jpg for footer and body.jpg for body.
I have created a small game in jquery.

Currently, My game scoreboard is showing only few text messages. I want to show them on some background image.

Below is my code which i am using to show text messages. Please help me so that i can display background images on them.

code:

```
     ......................
     ......................
        else {
        goldenGoal = false; 
        $("#message1").html("You Lose"); 
        $("#message1").css("color", "red");
          $("#message1").css("size", "190px");
        $("#play").html("Play Level Again");
        $("#lgoals").html(0);
        $("#vgoals").html(0);
        stats.loses++;
        //level = 1;
        //fps = 50;
        //difficulty = 0.2;
    }
       ..................
       ..................
```

Comment: Try doing a search on your issue first: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1787976/1538708

Comment: @adamb i first tried . I could't find it. so at last I question it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you have to do something like that:

```
$('#containerID').css('background-image', 'url(path/to/image.jpg)');
```

Or, in your example:

```
$('body').css('background-image', 'url(body.jpg)');
$('#header').css('background-image', 'url(header.jpg)');
$('#footer').css('background-image', 'url(footer.jpg)');
```

---

By the way, just as an input: Try to optimize your code. It's (unremarkably!) faster and just cleaner. Example:
Instead of

```
$("#message1").html("You Lose"); 
$("#message1").css("color", "red");
$("#message1").css("size", "190px");
```

You could do

```
$("#message1")
    .html("You Lose")
    .css({
        "color": "red",
        "size": "190px"
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this way:

```
$("#header").css({"color":"red", "background":"url(your image path)"});
```

Putting css for message1 div box with multiple lines is not a good idea but you can do this way to save your time and this will render a bit faster.